# Parsing an XML file and adding a new key based on an existing key

Tags: xml, bash, methods, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I'm really looking for some advice on the best approach to tackling this in bash.

I have a XML file with 1000's of entries that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myList>
    <dataitem>
        <path>./5553 Subset 43d.zip</path>
        <name>5553 Subset 43d</name>
    </dataitem>
    <dataitem>
        <path>./Another file name here with spaces.zip</path>
        <name>Another file name here with spaces</name>
    </dataitem>
...
```

And I'd like to add an additional key to each `<dataitem>` using the `<name>` key's data with an mp4 extension, so it would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myList>
    <dataitem>
        <path>./5553 Subset 43d.zip</path>
        <name>5553 Subset 43d</name>
        <video>5553 Subset 43d.mp4</video>
    </dataitem>
    <dataitem>
        <path>./Another file name here with spaces.zip</path>
        <name>Another file name here with spaces</name>
        <video>Another file name here with spaces.mp4</video>
    </dataitem>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way with **`xmlstarlet`** tool:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s "//dataitem" -t elem -n video input.xml \
| xmlstarlet ed -u "//dataitem/video" -x "concat(./preceding-sibling::name/text(), '.mp4')"
```

The output should be as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myList>
  <dataitem>
    <path>./5553 Subset 43d.zip</path>
    <name>5553 Subset 43d</name>
    <video>5553 Subset 43d.mp4</video>
  </dataitem>
  <dataitem>
    <path>./Another file name here with spaces.zip</path>
    <name>Another file name here with spaces</name>
    <video>Another file name here with spaces.mp4</video>
  </dataitem>
...
```

Comment: This is such an elegant solution - much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML, with a bash call to [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html).

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dataitem">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
       <video><xsl:value-of select="concat(name, '.mp4')"/></video>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Bash** *(assuming local cd paths, using installed xsltproc)*

```sh
xsltproc -o Output.xml XSLTScript.xsl Input.xml
```

Comment: A great solution but a little extravagant for my needs. It's good to see how I might approach this for larger projects though. Thank you